# Running `code-oss` doesn't work after installing from local .deb package

Tags: linux, debian, visual-studio-code

I am trying to make a local `.deb` package of `vscode` from source for the **amd64** platform. I followed this guide [here](https://gist.github.com/ted-piotrowski/e5c223a6a2f6f3079cb38c959ceecaa6), substituting `./node_modules/.bin/gulp vscode-linux-arm-build-deb` with `./node_modules/.bin/gulp vscode-linux-x64-build-deb`.

Installing the package gives me the following output:

```
user@localhost:~$ sudo dpkg -i vscode/.build/linux/deb/amd64/deb/code-oss_1.17.0-1505918194_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 391901 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../code-oss_1.17.0-1505918194_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking code-oss (1.17.0-1505918194) over (1.17.0-1505917413) ...
Setting up code-oss (1.17.0-1505918194) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/code-oss doesn't exist
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...
```

When I try to run `code-oss`, I get a command not found error.
Looking at `/usr/bin/code-oss`, it is a symbolic link to `/usr/share/bin/code-oss/bin/code-oss` and running `ls -l /usr/share/bin/code-oss/bin/code-oss` gives the error message `ls: cannot access '/usr/share/code-oss/bin/code-oss': No such file or directory`

I'm running Debian Testing and I had updated my software at the time of this attempt. Any help and/or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: are you sure the command is `code-oss` and not `code`?

Comment: [ifconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3339274/ifconfig) yes I am sure. Trying to run `code` gives me a command not found error.